# How to add Border between posts cards in grid template

Tags: html, css

How can I add Border in the bottom, between these three cards in the following code:
As I told above I just need to add the border-bottom line but I am not sure where to add this so could you help to resolve this issue?
Here is the code:

```css
img{
margin-right: 6px;
}
p{ margin:0;
}

body {
  max-width:350px;
  min-width:290px;
 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 1fr;
}
h2{
font-size:16px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
h2.remove-whitespace {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 55px;
}
.card{border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80" height="60px" width="100px" />
<H2 class="remove-whitespace">How the world is going to end all thsi baeses areblunt</H2>

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80" height="60px" width="100px" />

<H2 class="remove-whitespace">How the world is going to end all thsi baeses areblunt</H2>

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615147342761-9238e15d8b96?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1001&q=80" height="60px" width="100px" />

<H2 class="remove-whitespace">How the world is going to end all thsi baeses areblunt</H2>
```

Comment: add a photo showing where you want the border !!! It's not clear without a graphics !

Comment: hey check now! RUN CODE SNIPPET  is available!!!

Comment: add ``<hr/>`` after each ``<img>`` and ``<h2>`` tags.

Comment: or add ``border-bottom: 1px solid #111`` to the css for the h2 class. ``h2{
font-size:16px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}``

Comment: Wrap each "card" in it's own div...much neater

Comment: your hr thing is not working, but glad that your added css is working partially, mean it is only adding border to my post's title instead of entire box.

Comment: hey listen, i just edited all this code in w3school's try it box(as it is convenient) but whenever i add this code to my blogger website it disrupts all the web design of my site